# How to remove trailing null characters from String?

Tags: rust

I am having issues with removing trailing null characters from UTF-8 encoded strings:

[image]

How would one go about removing these characters from a `String`?

Here is the code I use to create the `String` from a `Vec`:

```
let mut data: Vec<u8> = vec![0; 512];
// populate data
let res = String::from_utf8(data).expect("Found invalid UTF-8");
```

Comment: Might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101915/how-to-implement-trim-for-vecu8

Comment: Is the padding all `\0`? Usually C strings contain one `\0` right after the string and every character after that might be garbage.

Comment: I'm glad you got the answer, but it really seems like the right answer here might be to not put the null bytes there to begin with. I'm assuming your snippet is not your actual real code, and only an example?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can trim custom patterns from a string using [`trim_matches`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim_matches). The pattern can be a null character:

```
fn main() {
    let mut data: Vec<u8>  = vec![0; 8];
    
    data[0] = 104;
    data[1] = 105;
    
    let res = String::from_utf8(data).expect("Found invalid UTF-8");
    println!("{}: {:?}", res.len(), res);
    // 8: "hi\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}"
    
    let res = res.trim_matches(char::from(0));
    println!("{}: {:?}", res.len(), res);
    // 2: "hi"
}
```

This removes 0 from both sides. If you only want to remove trailing 0s use [`trim_end_matches`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim_end_matches) instead.

Comment: Awesome! I knew there had to be an easy way to do this!

Comment: @T-Pane Btw, if the 0-bytes are there because you pre-allocate a data buffer you may be able to avoid them altogether by initializing the data with `Vec::with_capacity(512)` and filling it as required.