# Rust: Idiomatic way to save &str to bytes and then covert it back

Tags: string, rust

I would like to save a file name (at most 32 bytes) in a byte array, and then convert bytes back to `String`. Since there are a sequence of file names, the underlying array is designed to be fixed size (i.e, 32 bytes).

```rust
// name is the file name `&str`
let mut arr = [0u8; 32];
arr[..name.len()].copy_from_slice(name.as_bytes());
```

But the problem is: it is possible to get the file name the 32-byte long array (`arr`) without storing the length?

In C/C++, many built-in functions are offered due to the fact that the raw string is terminated with 0:

```cpp
// store
memcpy(arr, name.c_str(), name.length() + 1);
// convert it back
char *raw_name = reinterpret_cast<char*>(arr);
```

So, what is the idiomatic way to do it in Rust? A possible way is to explicitly store the size using an extra 5 bits, but it seems that it is not the best method.

Comment: Although 5 bits are necessary, it still occupies 1 byte in the implementation.

Comment: Could you describe more precise what you want to do? Even show your working c++ code that you would like to "translate" to rust? I'm not sure what exact operations you want to perform.

Comment: In your C++ example, the re-conversion is not to a `string`.

Comment: @thebusybee In C++, converting a C-style string to `std::string` is trivial (e.g, using std::string's constructor).

Comment: Well, then I would show it, if I were you. You are claiming that you convert a `string` to `uint8_t []` and back. The `reinterpret_cast` is not a conversion, just a possibly necessary hack. In the generated machine code it vanishes in nearly all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I' dont know what `reinterpret_cast<char*>` exactly do in C. But I think you can do similar thing with `std::str::from_utf8`

```
    let name ="hello";
    let mut arr = [0u8; 32];
    arr[..name.len()].copy_from_slice(name.as_bytes());
    println!("{:?}",arr);
    //[104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    let recoverd_str = std::str::from_utf8(arr.as_slice()).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}",recoverd_str);
    //"hello\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
    println!("{}",recoverd_str);
    //hello
```

However, `recovered_str` and `name` is not actually same... but you can trim the trailing null bytes! Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49406517/how-to-remove-trailing-null-characters-from-string).

Comment: @chenzhongpu Why would the underlying array contain any unintended bytes? It should only contain what you copied in with `copy_from_slice`, and that will be valid utf8 if you took it from `str::as_bytes`. (You won't even have to worry about graphemes being cut in half because `arr[..name.len()]` will panic if the entire string doesn't fit.)

Comment: C++ uses `reinterpret_cast<char*>(v)` as a quite dangerous construct that tells the compiler: "Interpret the expression `v` as a pointer to a `char` without any change." Commonly no machine code is omitted for this. C does not know this keyword, here a simple cast like `(char*)v` would be tried.

Comment: @Caesar Oh, my fault. It is okay to regard the 0 as the end of a valid string.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to convert a null-terminated `[0u8; 32]` to a `&str` would be through `CStr`, with `from_bytes_until_nul`:

```rust
CStr::from_bytes_until_nul(arr.as_slice()).unwrap().to_str().unwrap()
// Requires #![feature(cstr_from_bytes_until_nul)] pre Rust 1.69
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=909e833895fa81333603a4c08caec000)

However, this requires that a 0 byte is included in the slice, the maximum string length storable becomes 31 bytes. (Try reducing the array length to 5 in the playground to see what happens for 32 bytes long strings.)

If you want to be able to store 32 byte strings, you could use `std::str::from_utf8(arr.split(|&c| c == 0).next().unwrap()).unwrap()`, but I don't think that qualifies as idiomatic anymore…

Comment: `cstr_from_bytes_until_nul` has been stable since 1.69, so no more `#![feature(cstr_from_bytes_until_nul)]` required!